# Wordpress Main menu work but its sub menu does not show. How to show proper in header

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

```
<div class="nav_bot">

                    <div class="sub_nav">
                        
                        <?php
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location' => 'menu-2',
                    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                )
            );
            ?>

                    </div>
                    

                </div>
```

```
.nav_bot{height:65px;}
.nav_bot ul{overflow:hidden;zoom:1;}
.nav_bot ul li{float:left;}
.nav_bot ul li a{display:inline-block;line-height:65px;color:#fff;font-size: 14px;padding: 0 17px;}


.nav_bot li .sub_nav{position:absolute; z-index:99;top:126px;display:none;padding:8px 0 5px;*display:none;background:#fff;background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90)!important;filter:alpha(opacity=90);}
.nav_bot li .sub_nav dl{padding:5px 0 10px;}
.nav_bot li .sub_nav dl dd{position:relative;}
.nav_bot li .sub_nav dl dd a{color:#131313;padding:0 25px; display:block;line-height:39px;font-size:14px;text-transform:none;float:none;}
.nav_bot li .sub_nav dl dd a i{display:inline-block;width:6px;height:11px;vertical-align:middle;background:url("images/icons.png") no-repeat -70px -172px;margin:-2px 12px 0 0;}
.nav_bot li .sub_nav dl dd:hover a{color:#976b48;background:none;}
.nav_bot li .sub_nav dl dd:hover a i{background-position:-84px -172px;}
```

Comment: please remove sub_nav{display:none}

Answer (score 0):

In your code have sub_nav{display:none}.

Please remove it.

**(Display: none)** => will remove the element from DOM

Comment: I did remove the display none but its show all the menus which is under main menu. Sub menu also showing without formating.

Comment: For showing a particular sub_menu we may use one additional class like "active". We will write showing rules to that "active" class. For Example,
                                                     . sub_nav{display:none}
                                                     . sub_nav.active{display:block}
And we can handle this add/delete "active" class by our functionality not by css.